# Invalid syntax erroExpected 2D array, got 1D array instead for linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, missing-data, predict

this is my sample dataset

```
        RH
   0    79.8
   1    79.2
   2    79.4
   3    78.4
   4    77.8
```

My code is trying to replace the missing values in the dataset using linear regression but i am getting an error. 
why am i getting an error for this code of mine

```
linreg=LinearRegression()

datawithnull= taoRH["RH"].dropna()
datawithoutnull= datawithnull.dropna()

train_data_x= datawithoutnull.values.reshape(-1, 1)
train_data_y= datawithoutnull.values.reshape(-1, 1)

linreg.fit(train_data_x,train_data_y)

test_data= datawithnull.iloc[:]
rh_predicted[["RH"]]= pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))

datawithnull.RH.fillna(rh_predicted.RH,inplace=True)
```

i am getting this as the error

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[79.8 79.2 79.4 ... 75.2 74.2 74.9].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Add an appropriate LANGUAGE tag / LIBRARY tag.

Comment: @user2864740 hi, im not sure how to add a language/ library tag. i dont understand, do you have an example?

Comment: To the question.. like “python” and/or “pandas”. “R” is another common tool for various statistical analysis - tags help narrow the question, especially when about a specific implementation detail (like syntax).

Comment: i have already added them in the jupyter notebook